# How to send data from Arduino-uno using Bluetooth module HC-05 and read it in Android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am able to send data from my Android phone to my Arduino Uno using the HC-05 module. I also want to send data from the Arduino to my Android phone and I'm unable to do that.

**Question:** I will send a number from 0-9 using my android app to my Arduino Uno, the Arduino will send back the same number to my app, in words. For now, I am able to send numbers/letters to my Arduino from my app. I want help with the second part of the problem.

This is, in fact, a perfect duplicate of this question [Android - receive bluetooth data from Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864080/android-receive-bluetooth-data-from-arduino), but, unfortunately, this remains unanswered.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bbluetooth%5D+serial](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bbluetooth%5D+serial)?

Answer (score 4):

for receiving data from the arduino

```
UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() { 
     //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            String data = null;
            try {
                data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
                data.concat("/n");
                tvAppend(textView, data);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

and to send data from the arduino

```
serialPort.write(string.getBytes());
```

check the full [tutorial](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/control-an-arduino-using-your-phone/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you got the connection working fine:
In Arduino you need to use `btSerial.readStringUntil('#')`
You can change # with any character you want.
Then in Android append '#' to any string you're sending.
Also replace btSerial with your Bluetooth serial object